Can I replace these broken inserts on bathroom faucet?
The plastic hexagonal inserts inside my bathroom faucet handles are cracked and broken. Is it possible to replace only these inserts? I can't seem to find them online but I'm also not sure exactly what I should be looking for.
The sink brand is "SPA" which doesn't seem to be in business any longer. The top of the of the stem looks like the "B13" shape on the Home Depot chart. I'd be grateful for any advice. I'm wondering if I may need entirely new handles. Thank you

It's probably time for anew faucet.
